# RedBean.php fatal errors itself

Tags: php

Everything worked fine but today i start localhost and this happened, yesterday it worked fine i make 0 changes at all i don't know why this happened can someone help?

[image]
      Establishes a connection to the database using PHP PDO functionality. If a connection has already been established this method will simply return directly. This method also turns on UTF8 for the database and PDO-ERRMODE-EXCEPTION as well as PDO-FETCH-ASSOC.

```
    public function connect()
{
    if ( $this->isConnected ) return;
    try {
        $user = $this->connectInfo['user'];
        $pass = $this->connectInfo['pass'];

        $this->pdo = new PDO(
            $this->dsn,
            $user,
            $pass,
            array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            )
        );

        $this->setEncoding();
        $this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, TRUE );

        $this->isConnected = TRUE;
    } catch ( PDOException $exception ) {
        $matches = array();

        $dbname  = ( preg_match( '/dbname=(\w+)/', $this->dsn, $matches ) ) ? $matches[1] : '?';

        throw new PDOException( 'Could not connect to database (' . $dbname . ').', $exception->getCode() );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *fatal error*? You failed to mention in it.

Comment: Open the xampp control panel and ensure that MySql is running (green). If not then click its Start button.

Comment: it is green but don't works it worked fine i don't know what happened whole platform just stop working